# Railo REST API configuration not working

Tags: rest, railo

I was working to make a REST APIs in railo, but it seems some issues with my railo configuration.
My railo administrator keeps telling me that :

**"The REST Servlet is not configured in your enviroment"**.

So, I added the REST Servlet enabling code in my web.xml (located in my-website/WEB-INF/web.xml)

```html
 <servlet id="RESTServlet">
   <description>Railo Servlet for RESTful services</description>
   <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>    
   <servlet-class>railo.loader.servlet.RestServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>  
 
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

But its still not working.
When i tried to call the API, i gives me **404** error.
It looks like the railo server is not recognizing the **/rest/** part of the url.

The url is tried to access the REST API was like :

**{mysite}/rest/{rest-api-mapping-name}/{component-rest-parth}/{function-rest-path}**

Please tell me what am i doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What method did you use to deploy Railo? The Railo war? Does your CFML servlet get called correctly? (IE: are you able to run CFML templates okay?)

Comment: I am not sure about the deploy methd. but i think it was railo tomcat installer. Also, all other CFML templates are working perfectly.

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's happening. One last question: what OS & web server are you using? Apache on Linux perhaps?

Comment: The answer I posted below should address the 404 you're getting. The REST servlet definition should already be defined in the Tomcat default web.xml file, which is located in {railo install}/tomcat/conf/web.xml

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Apache on Linux with the Railo Installer then there is a quick modification you need to make to your Apache configuration in order to enable access to REST. In your main Apache config file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf on debian and /etc/httpd/httpd.conf in RHEL) you need to edit your Railo proxy config and uncomment the REST pattern match, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        <Proxy *>
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cf[cm])(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfchart)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.+\.cfml)(/.*)?$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/$1$2
        # optional mappings
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flex2gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flex2gateway/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/messagebroker/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/messagebroker/$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/flashservices/gateway(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/flashservices/gateway$1
        #ProxyPassMatch ^/openamf/gateway/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/openamf/gateway/$1
        ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8888/
</IfModule>
```

Specifically, this line needs to be uncommented:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/rest/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:8888/rest/$1
```

Let us know if this helps get rid of the 404 you're currently getting.

Comment: I know this is an old question. But I am getting a 404 with my REST API on Lucee 4.5/Apache/Tomcat with Windows 2008R2 IIS7. Do you know of a similar solution, using the web.config file?